# Grails MongoDb: saving map values with domain as value fails

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have 2 domain classes, User and Dog (for example)

```
class User { 
    String id
    Map<String, Dog> dogs
} 

class Dog {
    String name
}
```

My Controller get as an input a json

```
{"key" : "dogKey", "userId" : "someId", "dogName" : "dog"}

def addDog(){
    String key = request.JSON.key
    User user = User.get(request.JSON.userId)
    String dogName = request.JSON.dog
    ...
    if(! user.dogs){
        user.dogs = new HashMap<>(1)
    }

    user.dogs.put(key, new Dog(name: dogName))
    user.save(flush: true)
}
```

after running the user data @ Mongo is:

user:

```
{   _id:....,
    dogs: {
        "dogKey": null
    }...
}
```

can someone please explain me what i'm missing?

Thanks!

Roy

Comment: i've also tried the Custom User Types (explained @ mongodb grails plugin). it serialize all of the dog object (value: com.something.DogInstance) which is not what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

may be dog reference is not save in database

```
 def addDog(){
        String key = request.JSON.key
        User user = User.get(request.JSON.userId)
        String dogName = request.JSON.dog
        ...
        if(! user.dogs){
            user.dogs = new HashMap<>(1)
        }
        Dog dog =  new Dog(name: dogName)
          dog.save(flush:true)
        user.dogs.put(key, dog)
        user.save(flush: true)
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response. no connection. dog is not a document by itself (no _id) but an embedded one